# Prove $\lim_{x\to0}2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist at $x=0$.

Tags: limits

Prove $\lim_{x\to0}2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist at $x=0$.

Does this need an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, or is knowing it oscillates at 0 enough?

Comment: The first piece goes to $0$ by the Squeeze Theorem, if you are allowed to cite that, and the second piece oscillates, so the limit of the whole thing doesn't exist, but you should probably elaborate on the "oscillating" thing, say, find sequences $(x_n)$ and $(t_n)$ with $x_n \to 0$, $t_n \to 0$, and $(\cos(x_n))$ and $(\cos(t_n))$ converging to different values.

Answer (score 1):

can you use the Heine throem?

let $\dfrac{1}{a_n}=2k\pi$ and $\dfrac{1}{b_n}=2k\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then the limit has 2 different results

so the limit does not exist.

If a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof is necessary i would write afterwards.

let $\epsilon=1$    and $f(x)=2x\sin(\dfrac1x)-\cos(\dfrac1x)$

for any $\delta>0$ there exist a $x'$ and $x''$ $\in$ $U^o(0,\delta)$ and $\dfrac1{x'}=([\dfrac{1}{\pi\delta}]+1)\pi$  and $\dfrac1{x''}=([\dfrac{1}{\pi\delta}]+\dfrac32)\pi$

s.t. $丨f(x')-f(x'')丨=丨2x'\sin(\dfrac1{x'})-\cos(\dfrac1{x'})-2x''\sin(\dfrac1{x''})+\cos(\dfrac1{x''})丨\ge丨2x'\sin(\dfrac1{x'})--2x''\sin(\dfrac1{x''})丨+丨\cos(\dfrac1{x''})-\cos(\dfrac1{x'})丨\ge 丨\cos(\dfrac1{x''})-\cos(\dfrac1{x'})丨>\epsilon=1$

Answer (score 0):

We see that $$\lim_{x \to 0} 2x \sin \frac {1}{x}=0 $$(well-known result and can be proved by Squeeze theorem.).

Now I will show that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \cos \frac {1}{x}$$ does not exist. 
For $\epsilon-\delta$ definition,use the following procedure.

Choose $\epsilon =1$ . Let $f(x)= \cos \frac {1}{x}$.
Take $\frac {1}{x_1}=2n \pi$ and $\frac {1}{x_2}=(2n+1) \pi$ where $n \in \Bbb N.$ We see that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=2 >1=\epsilon$ whereas $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$ which can be easily done by taking sufficiently large $n.$